# Refresh button on Flexigrid issue

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I just have one problem with Flexigrid.

On example [here](http://sanderkorvemaker.nl/test/flexigrid/) while Flexigrid getting data (when you hit refresh) on the button displays "Processing, please wait..." But on my web page don't display that. Flexigrid just get data. I put time delay on server (5 sec) but still the same. Does anyone knows how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call it use the option `procmsg: 'Processing, please wait ...'`

See https://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/source/browse/trunk/js/flexigrid.js line 37.

Comment: i saw that but i dont know how to use it

Comment: @user2758618 Could you set up your code in a jsfiddle? Cause the default is it should show it, rather than not.

Comment: @user2758618, Could you get the jsfiddle working as yours does? I've tried doing it myself, but i get the feeling your json url isnt in the same format as http://sanderkorvemaker.nl/test/flexigrid/post2.php

Comment: i don't use php. All php code is on django view. Getting data works for me, problem is just that. I dont have experience with jsfiddle :)

Comment: Well, itll be hard for me to test then. Try removing some of your options in js when you call $().flexigrid(...) like search terms. I think its failing to intialise properly.

Comment: Check your external references vs the sample site. JS/flexigrid version etc.